# In The Sword of Truth how do you get Subtractive Magic?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

I am reading Terry Goodkind's books to improve my English, but sometimes I miss some details.

It is said that Richard is the first wizard in thousands of years to be born with both sides of the Gift, however, you learn that there are other people who acquired it during their lives; Darken Rahl has it, the Sisters of the Dark have it.

How did they get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darken Rahl and the Sisters of the Dark have Subtractive magic because they are agents of The Keeper. They swear an oath to him, and in exchange The Keeper grants them power, youth and Subtractive magic.

So Richard is the first in a long time to be *born* with Subtractive power, but other people can get it… As long as they’re willing to sell their soul for eternity to evil…